# Write in one line

Tags: python

Can the following code be written in one line:

```
for num in range(2000, 3201):
    if num % 7 == 0 and num % 5 != 0:
        nums.append(str(num))
```

I think of:

```
(nums.append(str(num))) for num in range(2000, 3201) if (num % 7 == 0) and (num % 5 != 0)
```

but it is not working

Comment: You would need use list comprehension.

Comment: Since 2002 is the first number divisible by 7 after 2000, `range(2002, 3201, 7)` lets you skip the `num % 7 == 0` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it almost exactly right, exepct that you dont append in a list comprehension:

```
nums=[str(num) for num in range(2000, 3201) if (num % 7 == 0) and (num % 5 != 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
[str(num) for num in range(2000, 3201) if num % 7 == 0 and num % 5 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `if num % 7 == 0` is equivalent to `if not num % 7` and `if num % 5 != 0` is equivalent to `if num % 5`

```
nums = [str(num) for num in range(2000, 3201) if not num % 7 and num % 5]
```